# SUM rows only if all column values are not 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table with five columns (a, b, c, d, e) and I need to sum the values of a column but only if every column's value on that specific row is not 0.

Lets say the table I have is like this:

```
A | B | C | D | E 
––––––––––––––––––
1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2

1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1

1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 2
```

In this case, I only have to sum the values of row 2 and 3, since in row 1 there's a 0, but I am not really sure how to go about it

Comment: If you have limited number of columns , you can use WHERE B!=0 AND C!=0 AND D!=0 AND E!=0 . Did you try this?

Comment: it would be really helpful if you posted a desired result as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
    SUM(
       CASE WHEN A > 0 THEN A END
       +
       CASE WHEN B > 0 THEN B END
       +
       CASE WHEN C > 0 THEN C END
       +
       CASE WHEN D > 0 THEN D END
       +
       CASE WHEN E > 0 THEN E END
       )
       FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Are we certain that these numbers can never be `< 0`?

Comment: Only positive numbers will be considered for this. As per the input, there are no Negative values, So I assume there won't be any in the actual case

Comment: There are negative values but all I needed to change was <> instead of >, and it worked so thanks a lot!

Comment: @CarlosRamírez But adding `0` is the same as not adding when the value is `0`... This tautology doesn't answer the question you posed, which appears to be how to avoid adding/showing anything for rows in which any of the columns is `0`.

Comment: @underscore_d you are right, but in the end I just modified it a bit and that worked

Comment: If you had to modify it, it didn't answer your question, so it shouldn't be marked as the answer - or you asked a different question from what you really meant, so you should clarify that.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using `not in`:

```
select sum(a),sum(b), sum(c), sum(d), sum(e) 
from tbl 
where 0 not in (a, b, c, d, e)
```

[**Demonstration**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5336a/2)

Comment: Beware that this can result in unexpected behaviour if any of those columns can be `null`, although of course that's not evidenced in the given sample data.

Comment: @DotNetdeveloper How? That doesn't tell the OP whether there are any `0`s.

Comment: @DotNetdeveloper No. You need to learn what `coalesce()` does, and to try things before posting. `Coalesce()` simply returns the first non-`null` value in the list of arguments. If the first number was not `0`, it would return that number, which is non-`0` and non-`null` and thus 'OK' according to your logic - thus completely masking the fact that there could be a `0` later in the list, which the OP wants to detect, which this would miss.

Comment: @underscore_d sorry boss, that was not my answer . I just wanted to know what if same condition was applied to 0. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps...

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,0,2,1,2),
                 (1,1,1,2,1),
                 (1,3,4,5,2)) V(a,b,c,d,e))
SELECT CASE WHEN 0 NOT IN(a,b,c,d,e) THEN a+b+c+d+e END AS SumValue
FROM VTE;
```

The OP doesn't state what that want returned in the event a row does have a `0`, so returned I returned *`NULL`*.